# How to interface with a DLL in R?

Tags: c++, c, r, command-line, dllimport

I created dll extensions from Matlab. Then, I want to read that dll in R.

I used `dyn.load()` but it does not works.

May you give me some suggestion?

Comment: Off the top of my head this seems unlikely to work at all.  What are you trying to do?  You *might* be able to wrap the call to the dll in a bit of C code that could then be linked appropriately and called from R ...

Answer (score 2):

What language was the source code written in?

The trouble is mixing compilers. The Matlab dll is likely to have been built by Visual Studio.
And you simply cannot mix C++ code between different compilers as function identifiers get mangled.  You can, with some work, mix C object code.  There are some FAQ on the MinGW site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comment thread below @Mario's answer: I was going to suggest you try the comparison you did (`R CMD SHLIB` dll vs Matlab dll) to help diagnose the problem.  Based on the result, I think that you need to figure out what the calling syntax for the dll would be in C and write a small C wrapper for it that uses that syntax but is in turn `R CMD SHLIB`-able ... `R CMD SHLIB --help` says you can include linker options on the command line (i.e. making sure that you are linking your Matlab-callable dll with your R-callable dll), but I'm not sure of the precise syntax. It would probably help to study relevant section of the R Extensions manual a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information is necessary. The regular way to do it is like this:

dyn.load("/path/to/library");

Some pointers:

- make sure that the architecture of the library is correct (e.g. 'x86_64' vs 'i386' vs 'armv7')
- make sure that you're not trying to load a windows '.dll' on unix-based machines ('.so', '.dylib')

Comment: Hmmm. Is this really going to work?  I would be a little surprised if a Matlab-compiled dll had the right interface to be called from R ... I guess if you know exactly what the expected calling protocol is (i.e. the types and order of all variables) it could work ...   PS, to the original poster: can you give more information about what "does not work" means?  what did you try, what was the error message ... ?

Comment: This is the error   dyn.load("sta.dll",F) # load globally Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/grojas/Documents/sta.dll': LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Is `file.exists("C:/Users/grojas/Documents/sta.dll")` equal to `TRUE`?  (i.e., maybe you just haven't set your working directory correctly?  Try `setwd([appropriate directory])` or `dyn.load(file.choose())` ?

Comment: If I create a dll with R CMD SHLIB I can read it from R, but if I use the dll created with Matlab I cannot read from R.